# Cambiar el color de la barra de estado en versiones menores a Android 5.0

Tags: android

Tengo una duda respecto a la forma de poder cambiar el color de la barra de estado (StatusBar) de mi aplicación cuando la versión del *SDK* en el dispositivo sea mayor o igual a **4.0 (API 14)**. 
Actualmente tengo lo siguiente para cuando el *SDK* es mayor o igual a la **versión 5.0 (API 21)** y la cual me funciona correctamente:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);        
    isColorNotifications();
  }

  ....
  ....

  private void isColorNotifications(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
    }
  }    
}
```

Tal vez alguien me pueda dar alguna pista.

De antemano Gracias.

Comment: Prueba con el plugin Android System Bar Tint, https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint

Comment: quizas esto le ayude https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/ Saludos

Comment: @BrandoT veo que tu pregunta es de hace tiempo, acabo de agregar una respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 3):

Buena pregunta, esto fue requerimiento del diseño en una de nuestras aplicaciones Android, por lo cual tuvimos la tarea de buscar como poder cambiar el color de la barra de estado.

Desafortunadamente nos encontramos que para dispositivos pre-Lollipop (-5.0) no hay forma en que programáticamente se pueda cambiar el color de la **barra de estado**, incluso difícilmente podría realizarse mediante una futura versión de la librería de soporte.

> Importante comentar que esta información fue dicha por ingenieros de
>   Google.

Comment: Gracias @Elenasys, tienes razón, no he visto una alternativa para la versión que planteo trabajar.